# How to modify Page Py output

Tags: python, tkinter

I just moved from Matlab to Python. So I am looking hopefully to re-build my GUI in Matlab Guide with Page Python (only hopeful for better performance for big data) 
I designed several Push Buttons and inside the code I try to write the below code just beneath Button1.configure.
I can not take out seop value from this clicked () function although I even define it as global variable. I need seop for whole the program.

```
  self.Button1.configure(text='''Data''')
    def clicked():
            global seop
            from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
            fname = filedialog.askopenfilename (initialdir="C:\Sgty")
            import numpy as np
            seop = np.loadtxt (fname)
            messagebox.showinfo ('Data Import', 'Int')

    s1 = self.Button1.configure (command=clicked, text="Import Data")
```